# Arm for Tor Relay Bandwidth Descrepancies

Tags: relays, debian, bandwidth, nyx, raspbian

I'm running a Tor Relay on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian. I installed Arm as to monitor bandwidth. The line that says "Bandwidth (limit: 800.0 Kb/s, burst: 1.5 Mb/s, measured 160 b/s)" claims my relaying is only relaying at 160 b/s. However, at times the graphs and their associated current download and upload speeds boast such averages as 90 Kb/s up to 200 Kb/s. Globe tells a similar story as the former reading.

What is causing these discrepancies?

Comment: It is unfortunate, but you are not alone. There are known problems with computing the Tor relay measured bandwidth and consensus weight, and it looks like work is ongoing, but the issues are not yet resolved. See for example [Fixing the Tor network’s bandwidth measurement system](https://lwn.net/Articles/646381/), and more recently [\[tor-relays\] More consensus weight problems](https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-relays/2015-June/007167.html).

Answer (score 2):

The measured bandwidth is mostly determined by external measurements by the Bandwidth Authorities. The following should help explain it...

https://blog.torproject.org/blog/lifecycle-of-a-new-relay

Comment: I understand that my relay may not be used to its fully capacity in the beginning, as according  to the article. (Great article! Found it a few days independently of this issue.) However my issue is that ARM is telling me something different then the Bandwidth Authorities are measuring. My question is why is this happening. (i.e. What is causing the discrepancies in bandwidth from what ARM thinks to what the Bandwidth Authorities think?)